# Rails, get column name of value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might be a little odd, but how can I get the column name from object in my model?

For example, I have a table which happens to have all 50 states in it as separate columns (I know, I know that could be way more efficient), so they look like:

```
al_allowed, ak_allowed, etc...
```

These columns are booleans, but I wanted to know in my model how to get the column names?, for example if for a particular record (in this case Campaigns), I want to see which states are checked off, and if they are True, I want to push the states abbreviation(the column name) into an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get an array of column names from an ActiveRecord model by calling the [`column_names`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001811) method. It's a class method, not an instance method, so you would use `Campaign.column_names`.